# Wire loom clip behind Lexus alternator has little play

Tags: alternator, lexus, clips

I was following along this [lexus alternator replacement](https://youtu.be/4v0CApBqJLY?t=750) tutorial, and at 12:32, the guy uses a 10mm wrench to release the clip on the alternator L bracket very easily.

I used his trick with much success up to this point, but my clip looks slightly angled, and the two clip releases doesn't seem to have much play in the slightest. I can't seem to reinsert the clip when pushing the wire from the bottom either.

At this point, I can't think of anything to release the clip. Is there a tool, or technique to release this clip?

Comment: I take it, there's a push clip which goes into a bracket which has to be released? Does this push clip serve any other purpose besides holding the wire in place?

Comment: It seems to hold the wire in place, to the metal bracket. Might try to separate the bracket from the alternator, now that I have access to the clip

Comment: If you just cannot get it to release, just yank it out being careful not to damage the wiring. Those clips (if it is what I think it is) can be reshaped correctly and stuck back into shape, easily re-inserted. You can probably use a flat tip screwdriver to separate it. Even if you break the clip, it's not the end of the world.

Comment: If you cannot release the clip, then how do you get to a position of re-inserting the clip?

Comment: I could reach behind the wire the clip was holding to attempt to push the clip in from behind. Had very little space to use pliers, and could not use the 10mm wrench trick. Ultimately a mechanic came over and he managed to get the clip open without removing the L bracket, using an hand held driver, and some hand work magic.